# UIWebDocumentView _updateSubviewCaches Crash in ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, crashlytics

**Can any one help me here?**

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000005de6fbeb8
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  2
Thread 2 name:
Thread 2 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001824a4150 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x0000000189d899b8 -[UIWebDocumentView _updateSubviewCaches] + 40 (UIWebDocumentView.m:2683)
2   UIKit                           0x0000000189baf8a8 -[UIWebDocumentView subviews] + 92 (UIWebDocumentView.m:2711)
3   UIKit                           0x0000000189e5e04c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) _wantsReapplicationOfAutoLayoutWithLayoutDirtyOnEntry:] + 72 (UIView.m:14065)
4   UIKit                           0x0000000189b5d0b4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1256 (UIView.m:14236)
5   QuartzCore                      0x0000000186d4d274 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148 (CALayer.mm:8937)
6   QuartzCore                      0x0000000186d41de8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292 (CALayer.mm:8817)
7   QuartzCore                      0x0000000186d41ca8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32 (CALayer.mm:2345)
8   QuartzCore                      0x0000000186cbd34c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252 (CAContextInternal.mm:1689)
9   QuartzCore                      0x0000000186ce43ac CA::Transaction::commit() + 504 (CATransactionInternal.mm:420)
10  QuartzCore                      0x0000000186ce4e78 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 120 (CATransactionInternal.mm:793)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839dc9a8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1802)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001839da630 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372 (CFRunLoop.c:1898)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018390adc4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 456 (CFRunLoop.c:3114)
14  WebCore                         0x00000001885dc608 RunWebThread(void*) + 456 (WebCoreThread.mm:694)
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182af168c _pthread_body + 240 (pthread.c:697)
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182af159c _pthread_start + 284 (pthread.c:744)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000182aeecb4 thread_start + 4
```

Comment: How id defined your webView? How is it created?

Comment: Via xib in storyboard